# Buscar registro por nombre, fecha y hora y que solo entregue el primer registro por día en un rango de fechas en MySQL

Tags: mysql

Mi tabla contiene estos datos y estructura:

| Nombre | Fecha | Hora |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alejandro | 2024/01/02 | 16:11:30 |
| Carlos 12 | 2024/01/03 | 09:25:20 |
| Diana1234 | 2024/01/02 | 08:20:32 |
| Alejandro | 2024/01/03 | 09:15:10 |
| Alejandro | 2024/01/02 | 14:05:33 |
| Alejandro | 2024/01/02 | 08:20:32 |

En esta muestra de tabla necesitamos que entregue algo así:

| Nombre | Fecha | Hora |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Alejandro | 2024/01/02 | 08:20:32 |
| Alejandro | 2024/01/03 | 09:15:10 |

La consulta es traer el registro dentro del rango de fecha y que contenga el de menor hora por día, si no me equivoco algo así como el top mínimo por hora y día.

Esta es mi consulta:

```
SELECT * 
FROM mi_tabla 
WHERE Nombre = 'Alejandro' AND Date BETWEEN '2024-01-01' AND '2024-01-20' ORDER BY Hora AND 
ORDER BY Date Asc LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Intente este Query pero no funciono:
SELECT * FROM mi_tabla
WHERE Nombre = 'Alejandro' 
AND Date BETWEEN '2024-01-01' 
AND '2024-01-20'
ORDER BY Hora AND 
ORDER BY Date Asc LIMIT 1;

Comment: Hola Mani podrias decir si la respuesta dada te resulto util y en caso de haberlo sido marcarla como aceptada, gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
 nombre,
 Fecha,
 Min(hora)
from Tabla
where nombre = 'Alejandro'
and Fecha between '2024-01-01' and '2024-01-20'
group by nombre, fecha
```

La clave está en hacer uso de la **cláusula group by**, la cual te agrupa los registros por los campos que le indiques. En la **cláusula select** haces uso también de la **función de agregación min** aplicada al **campo hora**. En resumen esta consulta lo que hace es crear grupos de registros que tengan el mismo nombre y la misma fecha y por cada grupo seleccionas el registro con la menor hora.